# Get all address of a customer using rest Magento2

Tags: magento2, customer-account-data-api

How to get all addresses of a customer using rest Magento2? Is there any out of the box API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, given you have the customer ID:

```
GET /V1/customers/{customerId}
```

this will return all the customer addresses

```
"customer": 
{
  "id": 0,
  "default_billing": "string",
  "default_shipping": "string",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "customer_id": 0,
      "region": {
        "region_code": "string",
        "region": "string",
        "region_id": 0,
        "extension_attributes": {}
      },
      "region_id": 0,
      "country_id": "string",
      "street": [
        "string"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi i am new to API, i am try to get customer by using API, my workout : 127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/customer -> its return error, i have found some knowledge from google they said you pass token, i dont know how can i pass token, but i know my token -> https://snag.gy/QbHmRs.jpg  how can i use it? can you pls help me? @sissy

Comment: My account not wokirng properly i cant able to post, can you pls help me  by here?

Comment: Try to write down a post explaining what you've done, it is impossible for me to help you with comments or chat, sorry

Comment: Thank you at least your reply.